# On what partition is Ubuntu installed?

Tags: windows-7, system-installation

I want to reinstall windows 7, but I don’t know where Ubuntu is installed. I want to format the windows 7 partition to remove all existing files, but I am afraid I will remove Ubuntu by accident. I was looking, but I didn't understand anything:

[image: http://s17.postimg.org/abq0hfcqn/Screenshot_from_2014_03_30_10_08_42.png]

Does this means that Ubuntu is installed in the first volume here in Windows:
[image]

Or are they both on the same volume (C:)? Looking at Windows disk management, the first volume seems to be empty, so maybe Ubuntu is installed in the same partition as Windows?

In `Gparted` it is shown as:

[image]

Comment: post the screenshot of gparted partition editor.

Comment: http://s9.postimg.org/93vog8x5b/Screenshot_from_2014_03_30_10_51_40.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

From the above screenshot, it was clearly shown that your Ubuntu OS is installed in `/dev/sda5` logical partition.

So don't touch your extended partition while reinstalling your Windows.Just format your `/dev/sda2` ntfs partition and reinstall Windows on it by choosing the custom option during Windows installation.